# Can i stop my cat being afraid of me?

Tags: cats

Me and my cat were really close but I was walking up the stairs with my cat in my arms and I slipped at the top and fell with him. He didn’t hurt anything and he’s still fine- he still plays and jumps around and does everything normally- but when ever I go up to him with my arms out to stroke him or play with him, he always tried to run away or bite me like he’s scared. How do I make him stop being scared of me?

Answer (score 5):

How long has it been since that happened? If it hasn't been very long, my advice would be to just give it time. Don't try to pick up your cat for now. And let him take his time coming to you. Reach out one hand to offer it. If he sniffs it and doesn't move away, then you can pet him. But don't try to carry him. Once he is comfortable with being pet again, then you can start working toward picking him up again.